# Region of Convergence

Tags: z-transform, transform

In attached [image: ROC] image why does the ROC have these values for 
$$
X(z) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}} - \frac{1}{1-2z^{-1}}
~~~~~,~~~~~ 1/3 < |z| < 2
$$

and for 
$$
Y(z) = \frac{5}{1-\frac{1}{3}z^{-1}} - \frac{5}{1- \frac{2}{3}z^{-1}}
~~~~~,~~~~~  2/3< |z| 
$$

Also why is ROC for $X(z)$ between 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

According to the properties of Z-transform, the ROC of sum of two signals is the intersection of their individual ROCs.

If you look at the signal 
$$ x[n] = (\frac{1}{3})^n u[n] + (2)^n u[-n-1] $$

you see that it consists of two signals; one right sided $(\frac{1}{3})^n u[n]$ with a pole at $z = 1/3$ and whose Z-transform is $X(z) = 1/(1 - (1/3)z^{-1})$ and with region of convergence ROC1: $ |z| > 1/3$ and the other is a left sided one $(2)^n u[-n-1]$ with a pole at $z=2$ whose Z-transform is $-1/(1-2z^{-1})$ and with ROC2 as $ |z| < 2$. Therefore, the intersection of their ROCs is
$$ROC_x = ROC1 \cap ROC2 = \{ 1/3 < |z| \} \cap \{|z| < 2 \} = \{ 1/3 < |z| < 2 \} $$

similarly for the signal $y[n]$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Can you please comment on the following: 1) how to determine the > or < sign for ROC. 2)Also, what determines whether a system is right- or left-sided. 3)and when is a^n u[n]  term & a^n [-n-1] are used ?

Comment: $x[n] = a^n u[n]$ is a causal, right sided sequence whereas $x[n] = a^n u[-n-1]$ is a anti-causal left sided sequence. Right sided sequences have ROC |z|>pole_max and left sided sequences have ROC |z|<pole_min.